# prove the following about orthogonal basis in n dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $\mathbf{z}_1,\mathbf{z}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{z}_{n-1},\mathbf{y}$ represent orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then how to prove the following
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\alpha_i\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{z}_i = 0
\end{equation}
where, $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think the equation is true because $\mathbf{y}$ is orthogonal to each of $\mathbf{z}_i$. I just realised it.

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Comment: Do you realize that y^{T}z_{i} is equal to the dot product of y with z_{i}?